# Android app design

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this [design](http://subefotos.com/ver/?77160bbe1b660b72783b5a6627aae6e4o.png) in eclipse

But in a galaxyS3 looks like [this](http://subefotos.com/ver/?c0793337a662b5044d4cd5bf16018e6eo.png)

I tried doing it with `GridLayout`, but it didnt worked.

The idea occurs to me to make, use a table of 3 * 3. See image below. This is my desired outcome:

[image]

layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.php_mysql_sqlite.Expediente_v_s_movil" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_empresa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="285dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_regresarS"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="regresar"
    android:text="@string/bt_regresar" />
```

the code of @drawable/customborder is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:thickness="0dp"
   android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="1dp"
     android:color="#4799E8"/>
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

1. how can I do to have that design
2. why changes the background

Thanks to all

PS: If I get negative points, leave a comment of reason, as it has happened before and can not do wrong

Comment: Which one is your desired outcome? the design in Eclipse, the result in s3, or the third image? It might useful if you showed us what you want using this tool. http://fluidui.com (it's free for up to 10 screens)

Comment: @StephanBranczyk As the third

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing:

android:fillViewport="true"

attribute for your ScrollView and so it doesn't fill the whole screen. Documentation for it is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. However, I would recomend you to use android:layout_width="match_parent" instead of "hardcoding" size.
   Moreover, if you want a "vertical blue line" just like the excel, I would recomend add another "Linear layout" inside linearMain. Just like this:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/parent"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/blue_line"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_weight=".5"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:orientation="vertical" >
           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/linearMain"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_weight=".95"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:orientation="vertical" >
           </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Your background is changed because of this statement  android:background="@drawable/customborder", if you don't want a background, just remove that statement.

Comment: Sorry, the blue line is not important, the image would have to be: ubefotos.com/ver/?419cb6b66475bf04aab26bdd07392eb6o.png

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, and I have the solution

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_empresa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearMain1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight=".95"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearMain"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_regresarS"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:onClick="regresar"
    android:text="@string/bt_regresar" />

</LinearLayout>
```